# Orientation Preserving Isometries

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question:
Let $v,w\in R^2$ (where $v \neq w$). Suppose $g,h \in M_2$ are orientation-preserving isometries of the plane, and $gv=hv$ and $gw=hw$. Prove $g=h$.

My Attempt: Since g and h are orientation-preserving isometries, then they must be translations or rotations from a previous theorem. We can then proceed with a proof by contradiction, where we assume that they are different kinds of orientation-preserving isometries, and then show that they must be the same.

I'm stuck on this part of the execution of the proof...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h^{-1}g$ is an orientation preserving isometry that fixes two points, namely $v$ and $w$. A translation does not fix any points. A rotation fixes only one point. All that's left is for $h^{-1}g$ to be the identity. Therefore $h=g$.

Comment: Thanks! I was stumbling around that idea, but never quite pieced it together.